# Regex match numbers with commas and points

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match integers and floats using the `re` module. So if someone types one of the following input types, it should validate that it is a number:

```
- 1000
- 1.000
- 1,000
- ($1,000.98)
- -1.000
- 1.0
- $1,0000
```

Right now I am using the following:

```
"^[-+]?[0-9]+$"
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the given input this regex should work:

```
^(?:[+-]|\()?\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/7)

**Breakup:**

- `^` - Start
- `(?:` - Start non-capturing group

  - `[+-]` - Match `+` or `-`
  - `|` - OR
  - `\(` - Match `(`
    `)?` - End non-capturing group (optional)
- `\$?` - Match `$` (optional)
- `\d+` - Match 1 or more digits
- `(?:` - Start non-capturing group

  - `,` - Match a comma
  - `\d+` - Match 1 or more digits
- `)*` - End non-capturing group (zero or more occurrence)
- `(?:` - Start non-capturing group

  - `\.` - Match a DOT
  - `\d+` - Match 1 or more digits
- `)?` - End non-capturing group (optional)
- `\)?` - Match a literal `)` (optional) in the end
- `$` - End

Answer (score 0):

Hi I messed around on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) and i got the following to match all 7 values

```
[0-9]?[-+.,]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+
```

Hope this helps, and here is [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlLcr.png)

Comment: Hi C.Molloy, this does not work as expected, because if it contains a string then it still matches - which is not what I want. The solution anubhava provided is more complete. But thanks for the help!